# Field replacement in Python

Tags: python, json

I have below code and output data.

```
json_rdd = data.toJSON().collect()
json_ls = [json.loads(x) for x in json_rdd]

[{'status': 'Yes', 'rec_id': {'oid': '5d9f5434523b7e0719'}, 'lot_number': '8be4-400d-a0c7-7214132dfd48'}, 
{'status': 'Yes', 'rec_id': {'oid': '5d9f5434523b7e071a'}, 'lot_number': '8be4-400d-a0c7-7214132dfd48'}, 
{'status': 'Take', 'rec_id': {'oid': '5d9f9f13523b7e0d89'}, 'lot_number': 'db53-4420-887f-0e9bb1364e2e'}, 
{'status': 'Take', 'rec_id': {'oid': '5d9f9f14523b7e0d8a'}, 'lot_number': 'db53-4420-887f-0e9bb1364e2e'}]
```

I need to change the above data like below (oid should be changed as rec_id), can anyone help me how to do that?

```
[{'status': 'Yes', 'rec_id': '5d9f5434523b7e0719', 'lot_number': '8be4-400d-a0c7-7214132dfd48'}, 
{'status': 'Yes', 'rec_id':  '5d9f5434523b7e071a', 'lot_number': '8be4-400d-a0c7-7214132dfd48'}, 
{'status': 'Take', 'rec_id': '5d9f9f13523b7e0d89', 'lot_number': 'db53-4420-887f-0e9bb1364e2e'}, 
{'status': 'Take', 'rec_id': '5d9f9f14523b7e0d8a', 'lot_number': 'db53-4420-887f-0e9bb1364e2e'}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply iterate over the list `json_ls` and for each item (which is a dictionary, lets call it `d`), set `d['rec_id'] = d['rec_id']['oid']`.

```
json_ls = [
    {'status': 'Yes', 'rec_id': {'oid': '5d9f5434523b7e0719'}, 'lot_number': '8be4-400d-a0c7-7214132dfd48'}, 
    {'status': 'Yes', 'rec_id': {'oid': '5d9f5434523b7e071a'}, 'lot_number': '8be4-400d-a0c7-7214132dfd48'}, 
    {'status': 'Take', 'rec_id': {'oid': '5d9f9f13523b7e0d89'}, 'lot_number': 'db53-4420-887f-0e9bb1364e2e'}, 
    {'status': 'Take', 'rec_id': {'oid': '5d9f9f14523b7e0d8a'}, 'lot_number': 'db53-4420-887f-0e9bb1364e2e'},
]


for d in json_ls:
    d['rec_id'] = d['rec_id']['oid']


assert json_ls == [
    {'status': 'Yes', 'rec_id': '5d9f5434523b7e0719', 'lot_number': '8be4-400d-a0c7-7214132dfd48'}, 
    {'status': 'Yes', 'rec_id':  '5d9f5434523b7e071a', 'lot_number': '8be4-400d-a0c7-7214132dfd48'}, 
    {'status': 'Take', 'rec_id': '5d9f9f13523b7e0d89', 'lot_number': 'db53-4420-887f-0e9bb1364e2e'}, 
    {'status': 'Take', 'rec_id': '5d9f9f14523b7e0d8a', 'lot_number': 'db53-4420-887f-0e9bb1364e2e'},
]
```

Comment: Thanks @Dipen. Looks like the above is going result only for last iteration. Do i need to append this data again to new list? I am not clear with assert json_ls

Comment: The list will be modified, no need to append anything. `assert` is to check if the answer is correct or not. You might want to read about how to use `assert`. It is very useful.

Comment: Oh sorry, i got it. Print(json_ls)

Comment: Great! No problem!

Comment: @ Dipen Dadhaniya, sorry the above code looks too confusing. I just want to addeach iteration data to recipients

Comment: Simply we can do:  d = {'recipients': []}

for ls in json_ls:
    d['recipients'].append(ls)
    
print(d)

Comment: No need to include any library. These are the lines: ["d = {'recipients': []}", "for ls in json_ls:", "d['recipients'].append(ls)", "print(d)"].